# Creating variable from XML localhost:8080 source in c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, variables

Ive been using the following code to call up data coming from localhost:8080 in xml format. This part of the code works fine:

```
    private void openP()
    {


        String sUrl = "http://localhost:8080/GetOpen=";
        XmlTextReader rssReader = new XmlTextReader(sUrl.ToString());
        XmlDocument rssDoc = new XmlDocument();

        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sUrl);

        Stream objStream;
        objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        WebResponse wr = wrGETURL.GetResponse();


    }
```

I want to know how I can now use the data that xhttp://localhost:8080/GetOpen= returns as a variable in my program.

for example if I were to goto xhttp://localhost:8080/GetOpen= in a web browser I would see this:

```
<Response>
    <Content>
        <Position Symbol="xVAR" Market="blah" >
    </Content>
</Response>
```

how would I go about making xVar a String variable that I can just simply write to a label?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `XmlDocument`, then you can use [`SelectSingleNode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method passing correct XPath to get particular part of the XML :

```
rssDoc.Load("http://localhost:8080/GetOpen=");
.....
XmlNode symbol = rssDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Position/@Symbol");
String symbolValue = "";
if(symbol != null) symbolValue = symbol.Value;
```

Comment: Ive just tried this solution now I get the error:Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'System.Xml.XmlAttribute'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @user3524727 fixed that bit